# What does the error "non-placement deallocation function"?

Tags: c++

I am getting the following error while compiling the serna-free package:

```
build/buildd-serna-free_4.3.0.20110221-2-i386-pAsDoD/serna-free-4.3.0.20110221/
  sfworks/common/RefCntStorage.h:76:10:
error: non-placement deallocation function 'static void
StringPrivate::RefCntData<E>::operator
delete(void*,StringPrivate::size_type) [with E = QChar,
StringPrivate::size_type = unsigned int]'
/build/buildd-serna-free_4.3.0.20110221-2-i386-pAsDoD/serna-free-4.3.0.20110221/
   sfworks/common/RefCntStorage.h:135:9:
error: selected for placement delete
```

Code looks like:

```
void operator delete(void* p, size_type)
{
    ::operator delete(p);
}
```

Comment: Looks like a change in gcc 4.5: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2991134&group_id=119701&atid=684730

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I **think** that the problem comes from this wording in the spec:

> If class T does not declare such an operator delete but does declare a member deallocation function named operator delete with exactly two parameters, the second of which has type std::size_t (18.1), then this function is a usual deallocation function

This would mean that if you tried to declare a pair `operator new` and `operator delete` that took a `size_t` as the second parameter, the compiler would think that your `operator delete` with this signature:

```
void operator delete (void* memory, size_t arg)
```

was the standard (non-placement) deallocator rather than the placement deallocator that's supposed to match `operator new(void*, size_t)`.

What's odd about this is that nowhere in the spec does it say that this should cause a compiler error.  In fact, the spec just says that if you have this error, then if the custom `new` throws an exception then the memory just won't get cleaned up.  If anyone knows why `g++` is reporting this as an error, I'd love to know why (*especially* if I'm wrong and this really is supposed to be illegal).

**EDIT**: Ah!  The problem seems to be from C++0x.  According to the most recent draft of the new standard, §3.5.4/20:

> If the lookup finds the two-parameter form of a usual deallocation function (3.7.4.2) and that function, considered as a placement deallocation function, would have been selected as a match for the allocation function, the program is ill-formed.

It specifically lists doing this as an example of what would cause the breakage.  The fact that this is new in C++0x would explain why the error only started popping up in the newest version of `g++`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the class was missing the single parameter non-placement delete operator. As can be seen on:

http://oorexx.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/oorexx/main/trunk/interpreter/memory/RexxMemory.hpp?r1=6219&r2=6218&pathrev=6219

and in more details in the bug report:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2991134&group_id=119701&atid=684730

> C++ PATCH for c++/34158 (template
>   placement delete)
>
> - From: Jason Merrill
> - To: gcc-patches List
> - Date: Tue, 10 Nov 2009 13:31:17 -0500
> - Subject: C++ PATCH for c++/34158 (template placement delete)
> - /* "If the lookup finds the two-parameter form of a usual
>     deallocation
> - function (3.7.4.2) and that function, considered as a placement
> - deallocation function, would have been selected as a match for the
> - allocation function, the program is ill-formed." */
> - if (non_placement_deallocation_fn_p (fn))
> - {
> - error ("non-placement deallocation function %q+D", fn);
> - error ("selected for placement delete");
> - }