# exception cleanup error on gcc 6.3 with C++14

Tags: gcc, c++14

I am trying to compile C++14 project of mine with gcc 6.3 and I am getting:

```
hm3/pairblob.cc: In static member function 'static std::unique_ptr<hm3::PairBlob> hm3::PairBlob::create(const hm3::PairBlob*)':
hm3/pairblob.cc:64:44: error: exception cleanup for this placement new selects non-placement operator delete [-fpermissive]
  std::unique_ptr<PairBlob> pair{ new(size) PairBlob };
                                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ext/new_allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/memory:63,
                 from hm3/pairblob.h:10,
                 from hm3/pairblob.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/new:125:6: note: 'void operator delete(void*, std::size_t)' is a usual (non-placement) deallocation function in C++14 (or with -fsized-deallocation)
 void operator delete(void*, std::size_t) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
      ^~~~~~~~
```

Code is relatively complicated but this is the part in question:

```
std::unique_ptr<PairBlob> PairBlob::create(const PairBlob *src){
    if (src == nullptr)
        return {};

    size_t const size = src->getBytes();

    std::unique_ptr<PairBlob> pair{ new(size) PairBlob };

    memcpy(pair.get(), src, size);

    return pair;
}
```

This `PairBlob::create` is a static method. `PairBlob` is a POD and have private default c-tor and have no d-tor:

```
struct PairBlob{
private:
    PairBlob() = default;

    static void *operator new(size_t, size_t const size){
        return ::operator new(size);
    }

    static void *operator new(size_t, size_t const size, const std::nothrow_t){
        return ::operator new(size, std::nothrow);
    }

// ...
```

Error appear only on C++14, compiling with C++11 is without error.
I am currently working on 32 bit ARM but I do not think this is related.

**UPDATE**

I found if I comment out the c-tor, code works. But in this case the c-tor is public and this is not what I want.

If I do code like this, it does give same error

```
PairBlob() noexcept = default;
```

**UPDATE**

I because I am providing `new` operators, I decided to provide `delete` as well. Now it compiles correctly. I did put some `noexcept` but they are not really required.

```
struct PairBlob{
private:
    PairBlob() = default;

    static void *operator new(size_t, size_t const size){
        return ::operator new(size);
    }

    static void *operator new(size_t, size_t const size, const std::nothrow_t) noexcept{
        return ::operator new(size, std::nothrow);
    }

public:
    // fixing C++14 error
    static void operator delete(void* memory){
        ::operator delete(memory);
    }
```

I am not posting this as answer, because I still do not understand why gcc can not use "normal" operator delete.

Comment: According to the error, your `unique_ptr` initialisation appears to be mapping to a placement-`new` somehow. That presumably is not what you actually want.

Comment: it is placement new - `new(size) PairBlob` . this is exactly what I want.

Comment: I can allocate space myself, check for errors, then memcpy over it, and finally give the result to unique_ptr, but if I do it this way it will be not C++ way. Also I want this to throw an exception if there is no memory

Comment: I must not know enough about placement `new`, as I don't see how passing it a `size_t` can do anything good. Anyway: `/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/new:125:6: note: 'void operator delete(void*, std::size_t)' is a usual (non-placement) deallocation function in C++14 (or with -fsized-deallocation)` Have you tried manually implementing a 'placement deallocation function' using a custom deleter? As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730403/how-to-delete-object-constructed-via-placement-new-operator. Edit: This one seems better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17656780/2757035

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the error "non-placement deallocation function"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367674/what-does-the-error-non-placement-deallocation-function) or perhaps better, [Placement deallocation function is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019041/placement-deallocation-function-is-not-called)

Comment: @underscore_d - saw it prior posting, it is similar, but not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer:

As of C++14, global function `void operator delete(void*, size_t) noexcept` is defined as a usual (non-placement) `delete` function, and thus is no longer considered a placement `delete` function (this behaviour matches `static` member function `void T::operator delete(void*, size_t) noexcept`, which is a usual `delete` function).  This means it can't match any placement `new` functions, causing the error when lookup discovers it while looking for `void* PairBlob::operator new(size_t, size_t)`'s match.

Adding `void PairBlob::operator delete(void*)` prevents lookup from discovering the aforementioned global `operator delete()` overload, and thus the placement `new` won't call a placement `delete` if the constructor throws.

---

### Long answer:

Compare the functions described in `[new.delete.single]` in C++11 and C++14 (all information other than `delete` function signatures omitted for brevity).

#### [C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/new.delete.single)

> ```
> void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept;
> void operator delete(void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept;
> ```

#### [C++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/new.delete.single)

> ```
> void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept;
> void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t size) noexcept;
> void operator delete(void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept;
> void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept;
> ```

<sup>Examination of [C++14 `[new.delete.single/14]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/new.delete.single#14) appears to indicate that if present, `size` must be the value implicitly passed to the usual `void* operator new(size_t)`, when called as `new Whatever`.</sup>

As specified in `[basic.stc.dynamic/2]`, out of these single-object `delete` functions, the following are implicitly declared, in global scope, in all translation units:

#### [C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.stc.dynamic#2)

> ```
> void operator delete(void*);
> ```

#### [C++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.stc.dynamic#2)

> ```
> void operator delete(void*) noexcept;
> void operator delete(void*, std::size_t) noexcept;
> ```

---

Similarly, in [C++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation#2), `[basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation/2]` contains this clause:

> The global `operator delete` with exactly two parameters, the second of which has type `std::size_t`, is a usual deallocation function.

This clause isn't present in the [C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation#2) version of `[basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation/2]`.

Furthermore, [footnote 37 in the C++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.stc.dynamic#footnote-37) version, referring to `operator delete(void* ptr, size_t) noexcept` and `operator delete[](void* ptr, size_t) noexcept`, states that:

> This deallocation function precludes use of an allocation function `void operator new(std::size_t, std::size_t)` as a placement allocation function ([[diff.cpp11.basic]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/diff.cpp11.basic)).

The linked page notes that this change may break valid C++11 code which relies on global function `void operator delete(void*, size_t) noexcept` being a placement `delete` function, causing the program to be ill-formed when compiled as C++14.  This matches the sized `delete` function's behaviour as a class member, where code that relies on `static` member function `void T::operator delete(void*, size_t) noexcept` being a placement `delete` function is ill-formed.

In regards to `static` member function `void T::operator delete(void*, size_t)`, `[basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation/2]` states, in both [C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation#2) and [C++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation#2), that:

> If a class `T` has a member deallocation function named `operator delete` with exactly one parameter, then that function is a usual deallocation function. If class `T` does not declare such an `operator delete` but does declare a member deallocation function named `operator delete` with exactly two parameters, the second of which has type `std::size_t`, then this function is a usual deallocation function.

<sup>Quote taken from C++14 version.  The C++11 version clarifies that "usual" means "non-placement", and links to `[support.types]` for a definition of `std::size_t`.  The C++14 version clarifies the meaning of "usual" before reaching this clause, and omits the link to `[support.types]`.</sup>

---

`[expr.new]` (specifically, [`[expr.new/20]` in C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.new#20), and [`[expr.new/22]` in C++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.new#22)) indicates that for a call to any placement `new` function, it will try to find a corresponding placement `delete` function via lookup, which will be called if the constructor throws when using that placement `new`; an `operator delete()` will be considered a match if its parameter list matches the `operator new()`'s parameter list (with the exception of the first parameter, which must always be `size_t` for `operator new()` and `void*` for `operator delete()`).  As deallocation functions [must be either global or class members](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.stc.dynamic#deallocation-1), name lookup rules state that when matching `T::operator new()`, it will fall back to the global `operator delete()`s if no member `operator delete()`s are found.  [See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a95473693dc773c9) for a demonstration of this behaviour.]

If a corresponding function is discovered by lookup, and that function is a placement `delete` function, all is well and good; if it's not, however, then the program is ill-formed.  Therein lies the rub; since `PairBlob` doesn't originally contain an `operator delete()`, lookup falls back to the global scope, and locates `void operator delete(void*, size_t)` (if present).  This is a placement `delete` function in C++11 or earlier (and may not even be present, in which case see the below paragraph), but an implicitly declared usual `delete` function in C++14 or later (and thus always present), meaning that any code which relies on it as a placement `delete` becomes ill-formed during the transition from C++11 to C++14.

If no corresponding function is discovered by lookup, however, then no placement `delete` function will be called if the constructor throws.  This is why adding `void PairBlob::operator delete(void*)` removes the error; as lookup stops when it finds this function, the global `operator delete(void*, size_t) noexcept` will not be discovered, and thus the program won't become ill-formed by trying to use it as a placement `delete` function.  [Note, however, that adding `void PairBlob::operator delete(void*, size_t)` would cause the same error as relying on the global one, as `static void T::operator delete(void*, size_t) noexcept` is also a usual delete function.]

GCC 6 defaults to C++14, [which has caused this to occur before](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=812058).  MSVC 2015 and later will also catch this, and emit error C2956; it doesn't appear to have a corresponding MSDN page at the moment, but [this bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1351894) explicitly refers to `[expr.new/22]` (albeit by its number, § 5.3.4/22, rather than its name).  Surprisingly, however, Clang fails to catch it, and will continue to treat `void operator delete(void*, size_t) noexcept` as a placement `delete`.  [Compare them [here](https://godbolt.org/g/o7QvdO), if you want.]

As mentioned on the GCC link above, the best solution is to modify the code to be compatible with C++14, but compiling with a previous C++ standard is a viable workaround.  Adding a member `operator delete()` that prevents name lookup from finding the global one does indeed prevent this problem, but I'm not sure whether it would be better to modify the placement `new` instead.